# segmentation fault при очистке выделенной памяти

Tags: c++, c, boost, динамические-массивы, com-port

Что я делаю не так ? 
Программа грубо говорят пишет в компорт пакет и читает ответ.
Пример кода:

```
void basicF(uint8_t comand)  
{
io_service io;
serial_port port(io);
switch(comand)
{
    case 0x01:
    {
        read_version_firmware_master*pack = make_read_firWare_master(1,0);
        int sizeOfPack = 13 + (int)pack->header.sizeData + 2; //13 - длина пакета. 2 - црц
        port.open("COM1");
        port.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));
        write(port,buffer(pack,sizeOfPack));
        printPack((unsigned char*)pack);
        port.close();
        delete pack;
        getAnsw();
        break;
    }

}

}
```

На данном этапе все корректно и программа работает.

```
void getAnsw()
{
io_service io;
serial_port port(io);
port.open("COM1");
port.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));
unsigned char c[13];
read(port, buffer(c,13));
uint16_t s = c[11];
printf("%hi\n", s);
unsigned char *b = new unsigned char [13+2+s];
for (int i=0;i<13;i++)
{
    b[i] = c[i];
}
read(port, buffer(b+13,(int)s+2));
port.close();
printPack(b);
if (checkCrc(b,(int)s))
{
    printf("%s\n", "package in client response is received");
}
else 
{
    printf("%s\n", "Error   ");
}

//delete [] b;
}
```

Теперь если раскоментировать освобождение памяти то программа выдает ошибку.
С чем это может быть связанно, указатель точно не нулевой так как я его передаю и вывожу значение на экран.

Comment: "Все корректно" - сильно сказано. Почему значение типа `uint16_t` вдруг печатается как как `%hi`???

Comment: @AnT наверное стоит воспользоваться гуглом перед тем как спрашивать такие вопросы, uint16 - 16 бит представления спецификатором вывода является %hi.

Comment: Наверное не надо слепо верить всему, что вам притаскивает гугл. Формат `%hi` предназначен для вывода значений типа `short int`, а не `uint16_t`. Именно `short int`. Если вам приспичило воспользоваться именно типом `uint16_t`, то его формат вывода записывается как `printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", s);` (после включения `inttypes.h`). Это не говоря уже о том, что в `printf` эти значения все равно будут передаваться как `int` и печатать их можно без всех этих выкрунтасов просто как `printf("%d\n", s);`

Comment: если уж вы пишете на с++, то возможно стоит отказаться от сишного printf и перейти на с++ный cout, спецификатор %hi - short int и для uint16_t будет работать некорректно. подробнее про спецификаторы тут http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: тип uint16_t тут кстати избыточен, я так понимаю вам нужен байт, байт это uint8_t

Comment: Далее по коду все выражения с `s` приводятся к типу `int`. Вот тип `int` и надо было использовать для `s` с самого начала,  чтобы потом не замусоривать код этими приведениями. Никакого повода для использования `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` или еще чего-то в этом роде тут нет.

Comment: Типы данных взяты не с потолка, по этому uint16. По поводу пользоваться cout , это дело привычки да и трушней писать по Си стайлу. Знаю очень много достаточно опытных программистов которые в ++ пользуются всеми возможными плюшками из простого СИ

Comment: @AnT short int - 16 бит. Следственно спецификатор не привязан к типу а к его размеру. Зачем так негативно пытаться доказать свою точку зрения? Тем более что она не совсем верна так как ссылаясь на документацию можно сделать вывод что спецификаторы завязаны на размерности типов а не их НАЗВАНИЕ

Comment: @Антон Игнатьев: `short int`: не 16 бит, а *как минимум* 16 бит. `uint16_t` (если он есть) - *ровно* 16 бит. Замечаете разницу? Вот именно поэтому `short int` и `uint16_t` имеют разные спецификаторы формата. Если в вашем случае `short int` имеет 16 бит - это не более чем совпадение. Это еще не говоря о том, что `short int`- знаковый тип, а `uint16_t` - беззнаковый. И нет, если вы хотите писать корректный код, то помните, что спецификаторы завязаны именно на конкретные типы, а не на их разрядность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логично. Создавайте массив правильно. Например, так

```
unsigned char *b = new unsigned char[19];
```

Но думаю, что  в этом случае лучше вообще просто объявить массив прямо на стеке

```
unsigned char b[19];
```

не нужно будет освобождать память, быстрее работает, меньше потребляет памяти.

Comment: Стыдно , но спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: А что у него было не так с массивом?

Comment: @ Pavel Mayorov создавала неправильно, не те скобочки у меня были

Comment: классическое UB:) а от него  может быть все что угодно. Например, падение.

Comment: @KoVadim последствия частого использования malloc в следствии чего невнемательность, машинально уже пишу круглые скобки.